# Tournament Bracket Algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm

i know there's a lot of the same questions out there. This is kind of more specific for this one.

First of all this is all build in PHP. I currently can create the first round but i seem to be having some problems with the ordering and figuring out the algorithm for the placements.

Say if we have 16 players the first round will look like this

```
1
16

9
8

5
12

13
4

3
14

11
6

7
10

15
2
```

I can't seem to figure out the algorithm for this thing. So far i make two arrays 
1 with the players in ranking order
1 with the number of players 
and i'm just taking the first, last from the players match them.
I need to match this order :/

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this. Consider this as an example:

First create your seed tournament.

```
$playoff_seed = range(1, 16);
$matchups = array();

// Then get each end of the elements

$x = 0;
while(count($playoff_seed) > 0) {
    $matchups[$x][] = array_shift($playoff_seed);
    $matchups[$x][] = array_pop($playoff_seed);
    $x++;
}

print_r($playoff_seed);
```

[Sample Fiddle](https://ideone.com/kSeyv9)

Comment: i'm sorry, maybe i didn't make it clear in my description. This is what i'm doing but the problem is that i need the correct order as it shows above. For example in the output you gave me it `$array[0]` should be `1,16` as it is but `$array[1]` should be `9,8` and so on